# Should I add a "the" before "headmaster" here?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, definite-articles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“To be elected chairman” vs. “to be elected the chairman”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32519/to-be-elected-chairman-vs-to-be-elected-the-chairman)
>   [Omission of “the” in “elected him president” and “made captain”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56365/omission-of-the-in-elected-him-president-and-made-captain)

> Dr. Peter Spence, ______ headmaster of the school, told us, “a fifth of pupils here go on to study at Oxford and Cambridge.”

Does it matter whether I add a "the" before "headmaster" here?

Comment: Is Dr Spence incidentally the headmaster? Or the headmaster's name happens to be Dr Peter Spence?

Comment: Related: [Should there be an article before “mayor” in “the role of mayor”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54837/), ["To be elected chairman" vs. "to be elected the chairman"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32519/), [Omission of “the” in “elected him president” and “made captain”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56365/)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to omit the definite article when a noun phrase names a particular role or job and when it is the complement (or subject predicative) of a copular verb such as *be*, so we can certainly say, for example, *He was headmaster of Hogwarts*. When the noun phrase is, as in your example, the subject of a clause, the omission of the definite article is more doubtful. As there is no harm in including it, you might as well use it. If you omit *of the school*, as you might want to, the definite article is obligatory in most contexts.

Comment: So there is no definite answer to definite article question then.

Comment: @user20908: Well, I could, I suppose, just have answered 'No'.